# add coordinates system into arcgis10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing

I must process an  Excel file data  but  the format of my longitude and latitude coordinate are: Lat: -22 to -34 and Long: 9 to 18 in decimal degree. So i want to use Add XY tool into Arcgis10 to put my coordinate data, but i have meet some difficulties because two latitude and two longitudes.
How to put the variation of latitude and longitude coordinates with Arcgis tool?

Comment: perhaps make two rows of data in your Excel file, one for each set of coordinates?

Comment: a point by definition can only have one latitude and one longitude point. Are you referring to a degrees minutes and seconds?

Comment: It sounds like you have a coordinate range rather than specific coordinates. That cannot be represented as points, only polygons - ie your four corners would be minx miny, minx maxy, maxx miny, and maxx maxy. Add XY is for specific coordinates. What does this data describe? Can you provide a screenshot or a few sample rows so we might better understand your data?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your spreadsheet so that Latitude and Longitude are in separate columns. Each point should have its own row with one X and one Y. Also make sure that you format your cells so that they are number values, sometimes ArcGIS is finicky about this. Use this image as a template:

[image]

Save your excel spreadsheet and close it.

(1) Open ArcGIS and add the data using the Add Data icon, which is probably sheet1 within your spreadsheet.

(2) In the table of contents, right click on your table (sheet1), and select "Display XY Data"

(3) Fill in the X and Y fields with your lat and long and select the appropriate coordinate system. **This should be a geographic coordinate system** (likely WGS1984 or NAD1983). Select OK and your data points should be populated on the map.