# Adding Maximum and Minimum Latitude and Longitude as features in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have an Excel file with the coordinates (Latitude/Longitude) for an area. The file contains the coordinate of two corners in the latitude/longitude format.

How can we do to use Python to iterate the process for all coordinates and to export into XY coordinates?

Example of my file:

```
N°1:  Min_Long   Max_Long  Min_Lat   Max_Lat
     1.5        2.833      6.25         7.33

N°2  -13        5          10          25
```

...
...

Or else is there a tool in ArcGIS similar to "Add X,Y Data" in ArcMap, that can be used to automatically add this lat/long format?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120765/add-coordinates-system-into-arcgis10 It appears you may have [accidentally created two accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

There is a code sample in the [Online Help for ListBookmarks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000060000000) that could be adapted to do this fairly quickly.

That code reads bookmarks from a map, whereas yours would need to use a search sursor to read rows from an Excel spreadsheet instead, but the harder part of using arcpy.da.InsertCursor to write your rectangles to a feature class would be identical.

You'll find the code under the heading of:

> **ListBookmarks example 3**
>
> This sample will convert each bookmark in a map document to a feature.